# API request limit for Google Visualization

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I am interested in using the Google Visualization API (the query class) for my site, querying a spreadsheet.

But I don't see any request or data limits documented on Google's site.

Does anyone know anything about limits to the API?

Thank you.